# Drawing Mirrored Text

Tags: iphone, text, drawing

I'm trying to draw mirrored (as in, it looks like you held it up to a mirror) text, and I want to do it the easiest way possible.

It is possible to do a transform on a UILabel? Or do I have to use Quartz and do CGContextShowTextAtPoint() ?

Comment: As in, similar to this: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/71a84c9b49.png

Comment: Did you try using UIView's transform property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a transform to the layer:

`[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0f, 1.0f)]`

<sup>but you will need a Ph.D. in horribleness.</sup>